# How to set DB2 global variable on session from spring data jpa context

Tags: jpa, db2, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring data jpa repository. I want to query a database view.
The database is DB2 and supports a feature called 'global variable' which actually is a session variable. The db view declaration uses a global variable.

How do I set the value of this variable at runtime before the view is executed?

Would something like this work?

```
public interface DomainRepository extends org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository<Domain, IdType> {
      @Query(value = "SET SCHEMA.VAR_GLOBAL = :param; SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.DOMAIN", nativeQuery = true)
      List<Domain> findByDomain(@Param("param") String param);
         }
```

Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what I want to achieve in SQL:

```
SET CURRENT APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY = 'V11R1';
SET SCHEMA.VAR_GL = 'Value';
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.VIEW;
```

The SCHEMA.VIEW is declared as:

```
SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE WHERE field = VAR_GL
```

I have to mark the public method on the controller with @Transactional annotation to execute the queries together in one db session.

```
public interface Controller {  
  @Transactional
  List<Options> loadOptions();
}
public class ControllerImpl implements Controller {
  @Autowired
  private DomainRepository repo;
  @Override
  public List<Option> loadOptions() {
    this.repo.setCompatibilityMode();
    this.repo.setGlobalVariableA("Value");
    List<Option> list = this.repo.loadDropdown();
    return list;
  }
```

In my jpa repository I need a method for each global variable:

```
public interface DomainRepository extends JpaCrudRepository<Option, OptionPK> {
  @Modifying
  @Query(value = "SET CURRENT APPLICATION COMPATIBILITY = 'V11R1'", nativeQuery = true)
      void setCompatibilityMode();    
  }
  @Modifying
  @Query(value = "set SCHEMA.VAR_GL = :value", nativeQuery = true)
  void setGlobalVariableA(@Param("value") String value);
  @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.VIEW", nativeQuery = true)
  List<Option> loadDropdown();
}
```

That's how it works. I'd like to improve this solution further but I have no idea how to make the variable query more reusable by making the variable name a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Variable declarations don't work over JDBC but temp tables do:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.myvars
(
VAR_GLOBAL VARCHAR(255)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Comment: Although you can certainly use a temporary table, there's no reason why global variables wouldn't work over JDBC.

Comment: Perhaps in `LUW` but I get `SQLCODE -104 SQLSTATE 42601` when trying to `CREATE VARIABLE` on zOS

Comment: Which version? Global variables are supported since DB2 for z/OS v11

Comment: `SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` returns `DSN10015`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot lump two statements together like in your example, but you should be able to create two different `Query`s and execute them in separate calls to `executeUpdate()` and `getResultList()` respectively. (I'm not very familiar with JPA, I may have used wrong method names, hopefully you get the idea.)

Comment: That's one point, I cannot concatenate statements in the Query annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CRUD methods:

```
public interface DomainRepository extends CrudRepository<Domain, Long>{
    List<Domain> findAll();
}
```